# XML & Lambda - accessing fields that don't implement the IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I'm using Linq/Lambda to write output to an XML file, just in the standard way:

```
new XElement("Employees",
            from emp in empList
            select new XElement("Employee",
                         new XAttribute("ID", emp.ID),
                           new XElement("FName", emp.FName),
                           new XElement("LName", emp.LName),
                           new XElement("DOB", emp.DOB),
                           new XElement("Sex", emp.Sex)
                       ));
```

The issue I'm running into in effect is that my emp class contains fields that don't implement the IEnumerable interface, but which themselves also contain fields (imagine, for example, the emp included a "WorkHistory" field, which itself contained a set of fields related to complaints, commendations, etc).  These latter fields are optional (and non-repeating) in the XML schema.

Is there any way of checking whether they have been set (i.e., whether they are null or not) given the Linq/Lambda framework? If they are not set, then the equivalent XML node needs to be absent.

Hope that made sense. I'm new to Linq/Lambda stuff, so sorry if it sounds confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple driver. In future, follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting.

You can do this [several ways](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/generate-xml-from-object-in-C-Sharp/). Out of curiosity, I tried out linq:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var empList = new List<Employee>();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                empList.Add(GenerateTestEmployee(i));
            }

            var xmlConverter = new XmlConverter();
            var employeesNode = new XElement(
                "Employees",
                empList.Select(emp => xmlConverter.Convert(emp))
            );

            Console.WriteLine(employeesNode.ToString());
        }

        private static Employee GenerateTestEmployee(int seed) {
            return new Employee() {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FName = seed.ToString(),
                LName = "Example",
                DOB = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-20).AddYears(-seed),
                Sex = seed % 2 == 0 ? "Male" : "Female",
                WorkHistory = GenerateTestWorkHistory(seed)
            };
        }

        private static WorkHistory GenerateTestWorkHistory(int seed) {
            if (seed % 7 == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return new WorkHistory() {
                Complaints = Enumerable.Repeat("Complaint!", seed % 2).ToList(),
                Commendations = Enumerable.Repeat("Commendation!", seed % 3).ToList()
            };
        }
    }

    public class Employee {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public WorkHistory WorkHistory { get; set; }

    }

    public class WorkHistory {
        public List<string> Complaints { get; set; }
        public List<string> Commendations { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlConverter {
        public XElement Convert(Employee emp) {
            var attributes = new List<XAttribute> { 
                new XAttribute("ID", emp.ID)
            };
            var elements = new List<XElement> {
                new XElement("FName", emp.FName),
                new XElement("LName", emp.LName),
                new XElement("DOB", emp.DOB),
                new XElement("Sex", emp.Sex)
            };
            var workHistory = Convert(emp.WorkHistory);
            if (workHistory != null) {
                elements.Add(workHistory);
            }
            return new XElement("Employee", attributes, elements);
        }

        private XElement Convert(WorkHistory hist) {
            if (hist == null) {
                return null;
            }

            var elements = new List<XElement>();
            if (hist.Complaints != null && hist.Complaints.Any()) {
                var complaints = new XElement(
                   "Complaints",
                   hist.Complaints.Select(comp => new XElement("Complaint", comp))
               );
               elements.Add(complaints);
            }
            if (hist.Commendations != null && hist.Commendations.Any()) {
                var commendations = new XElement(
                   "Commendations",
                   hist.Commendations.Select(comm => new XElement("Commendation",comm))
               );
               elements.Add(commendations);
            }
            return elements.Any() ? new XElement("WorkHistory", elements)
                                  : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

PS: I find [this online IDE](http://rextester.com/) helpful for testing snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Using method syntax, as opposed to query syntax, you can build Employee element gradually, adding optional child elements only when it should :

```
new XElement("Employees",
    empList.Select(emp => {
        var xe = new XElement("Employee",
            new XAttribute("ID", emp.ID),
            ....
        ));

        // do further checks and add optional child elements accordingly
        if (emp.WorkHistory != null) xe.Add(new XElement(...));

        // return the final result
        return xe;
    })
)
```

Comment: Does this add WorkHistory as a child element of the Employee XElement?

Thanks!

Comment: @user5956088 yes it is